# Flutter : How to grab the value of a Checkbox in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox

I want to grab the value of check box after being altered. That is not happening getting the same initialized value. I created a custom Check box that will be called and pass on the value  of the checkbox that will determine weather the box is checked or not I am having trouble ho to grab that changed value when the form is submitted as that value will be needed in the future.... super new to flutter.

The Widget that I created

```
class  CCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  late bool value;
  late bool required;
  late String label;
  late String checkBoxErrorMessage="Please check this";

  CCheckBox ({Key? key, this.value=false, required this.label, this.required=false,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CCheckBox> createState() => _CCheckBoxState();
}

class _CCheckBoxState extends State<CCheckBox> {




  //Validation Function
  validateCheckbox(e){
    if(widget.required){
      if (widget.value==false) {
        return widget.checkBoxErrorMessage;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FormField<bool>(
        builder: (state) {
          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Checkbox(
                      value: widget.value,

                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.value = value!;
                          state.didChange(value);
                        });
                      }),
                  Text('I accept terms'),                  ],
              ),
//display error in matching theme
              Text(
                state.errorText ?? '',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.error,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
//output from validation will be displayed in state.errorText (above)
        validator: (bool? value) {
          return validateCheckbox(value);
        },
      ),
    ) ;
  }
}
```

The Value Initialized in the parent Widget

```
  late bool checkboxValue=false;
```

Calling the custom checkbox

```
 CCheckBox(value: checkboxValue, label: 'Agree To terms', required: true,),
```

On submitting the Form

```
 ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: (){print("this is the value of checkbox: {$checkboxValue}");}
    child: Text("Submit")
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MyCheckboxFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCheckboxFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.initialValue,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final bool initialValue;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  @override
  _MyCheckboxFormFieldState createState() => _MyCheckboxFormFieldState();
}

class _MyCheckboxFormFieldState extends State<MyCheckboxFormField> {
  late bool _isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isChecked = widget.initialValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CheckboxListTile(
      title: Text('I accept the terms and conditions'),
      value: _isChecked,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _isChecked = value;
        });
        widget.onChanged(value);
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late bool _isChecked;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isChecked = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            // other form fields
            validator: (value) {
              if (!_isChecked) {
                return 'Please accept the terms and conditions';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          MyCheckboxFormField(
            initialValue: _isChecked,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _isChecked = value;
              });
            },
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                // form is valid, do something
              }
            },
            child: Text('Submit'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code lacks some explanation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am a bit occupied in a project I will surely update this. Thank you